# How to add multiple checkboxes in elastic template agreement?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

How to add multiple checkboxes in the docusing elastic template?
[image: and]

and cannot add long text in the "Agreement Statement Text", how to over come this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Elastic templates, as they only support the one checkbox.

You could create a regular envelope, but the experience today would not be the same.

New functionality is coming soon to help support what you want, not sure it will be exactly the same as elastic templates with multiple checkboxes, but should be close enough.

Comment: is it possible to add long texts in the "Agreement Statement Text"?

Comment: not sure what is the maximum length, you can try and see what happens, it may not look that great, but worth a short....

Comment: can you give me the link for regular envelop creation?

Comment: https://account-d.docusign.com/ log in with developer account, and click to get signatures

Comment: Do it all from the web app first, not from code, to make sure it's what you need/want

Comment: Anything you do this way - you an also code from your app